# How to use nested functions with root.after() in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to use nested functions in `Tkinter` with `.after()` in the following code :

```
from tkinter import *

a=0

def fct1() :
    global a
    global b

    b=0
    text = Label(root, text="Hey!")
    text.pack()

    def fct2() :
        global b

        text2 = Label(root, text="Yes")
        text2.pack()

        b+=1
        if b>3 :
            return
        root.after(5,fct2)

    fct2()

    a+=1
    if a>5 :
        return
    root.after(25,fct1)



root = Tk()

fct1()

root.mainloop()
```

With this code, I want to display one "Hey!" in my Tkinter root, then run the function *fct2* which would display 4 "Yes", and then do it again 5 more times.

But when I run the code, 6 "Hey!" are displayed as expected, but in each one, we see that the number of "Yes" displayed look random whereas it should be 4 each time.
Does anyone have an idea why I have this problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I see a "hey" followed by 4x "yes" every time.

Comment: Really are you sure you get 4 "yes" each time ? When i run the code i get sometimes 3 "yes", sometimes 5 and sometimes 4

Comment: `fct2()` isn't going to be called at precise 5ms intervals; the time taken to create and pack the Label gets added to that.  It wouldn't take a whole lot of extra time (from the necessary resizing of the root window, perhaps) for the series of `fct2()`s to take longer than the 25ms interval between `fct1()`s.  Greatly increasing that `25` would avoid the problem.  You could also remove the `.after()` from `fct1()`, and instead have the final `fct2()` (where you currently just `return`) launch the next `fct1()`.